# Parsing a forum's RSS output to my needs in C#

Tags: c#, php, regex, rss

I want to parse the following RSS output to my needs:
http://forum.ragezone.com/external.php?type=RSS2&forumids=427

However, I'm not really familiar with Regex (which I suppose is what needed in this case). 
I have the following code to download the whole output as string:

```
 WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        Stream st = wc.OpenRead(textBox1.Text);

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(st))
        {
            Output = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

However, I'm not sure on how to parse it. Basically, each "item" - which is a thread, is apeparing like so:

```
    <item>
<title>
<![CDATA[ [Release] [Add-on] Choice Dialog Easy Selections ]]>
</title>
<link>
http://forum.ragezone.com/f427/add-choice-dialog-easy-selections-979948-new/
</link>
<pubDate>Tue, 07 Jan 2014 16:04:20 GMT</pubDate>
<description>
<![CDATA[
*Note:* This won't affect your current scripts or harm them, but you may add it to whatever you...
]]>
</description>
<content:encoded>
<![CDATA[
<div><b>Note:</b> This won't affect your current scripts or harm them, but you may add it to whatever you want.<br /> <b>Example of usage: </b><br /> <br /> Before:<br /> <div class="bbcode_container">
 <div class="bbcode_description">PHP Code:</div>
 <hr /><code class="bbcode_code"><code><span style="color: #000000"> <span style="color: #0000BB">cm</span><span style="color: #007700">.</span><span style="color: #0000BB">sendSimple</span><span style="color: #007700">(</span><span style="color: #DD0000">"Hey!&nbsp;\r\nPlease&nbsp;select&nbsp;an&nbsp;option.#b\r\n#L0#Option&nbsp;1.#l\r\n#L1#Option&nbsp;2.#l\r\n#L2#Option&nbsp;3.#l"</span><span style="color: #007700">);&nbsp;
<br /></span><span style="color: #0000BB"></span> </span> </code></code><hr />
 </div>After:<br /> <div class="bbcode_container">
 <div class="bbcode_description">PHP Code:</div>
 <hr /><code class="bbcode_code"><code><span style="color: #000000"> <span style="color: #0000BB">cm</span><span style="color: #007700">.</span><span style="color: #0000BB">sendSimple</span><span style="color: #007700">(</span><span style="color: #DD0000">"Hey!&nbsp;\r\nPlease&nbsp;select&nbsp;an&nbsp;option."</span><span style="color: #007700">,&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #DD0000">"Option&nbsp;1"</span><span style="color: #007700">,&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #DD0000">"Option&nbsp;2"</span><span style="color: #007700">,&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #DD0000">"Option&nbsp;3"</span><span style="color: #007700">);&nbsp;
<br /></span><span style="color: #0000BB"></span> </span> </code></code><hr />
 </div><b>How to add:</b>​<br /> <br /> Navigate to NPCConversationManager, replace your current sendSimple method with the following:<br /> <br /> <div class="bbcode_container">
 <div class="bbcode_description">PHP Code:</div>
 <hr /><code class="bbcode_code"><code><span style="color: #000000"> <span style="color: #0000BB"></span><span style="color: #007700">public&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">void&nbsp;sendSimple</span><span style="color: #007700">(</span><span style="color: #0000BB">String&nbsp;text</span><span style="color: #007700">,&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">String</span><span style="color: #007700">...&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">selections</span><span style="color: #007700">)&nbsp;{<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;if&nbsp;(</span><span style="color: #0000BB">selections</span><span style="color: #007700">.</span><span style="color: #0000BB">length&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #007700">&gt;&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">0</span><span style="color: #007700">)&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #FF8000">//&nbsp;Adding&nbsp;this&nbsp;even&nbsp;if&nbsp;selections&nbsp;length&nbsp;is&nbsp;0&nbsp;will&nbsp;do&nbsp;anything,&nbsp;but&nbsp;whatever.<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">text&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #007700">+=&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #DD0000">"#b\r\n"</span><span style="color: #007700">;<br /><br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;for&nbsp;(</span><span style="color: #0000BB">int&nbsp;i</span><span style="color: #007700">=</span><span style="color: #0000BB">0</span><span style="color: #007700">;&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">i</span><span style="color: #007700">&lt;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">selections</span><span style="color: #007700">.</span><span style="color: #0000BB">length</span><span style="color: #007700">;&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">i</span><span style="color: #007700">++)&nbsp;{<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">text&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #007700">+=&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #DD0000">"#L"&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #007700">+&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">i&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #007700">+&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #DD0000">"#"&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #007700">+&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">selections</span><span style="color: #007700">&#91;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">i</span><span style="color: #007700">&#93;&nbsp;+&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #DD0000">"#l\r\n"</span><span style="color: #007700">;<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;}<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">sendSimple</span><span style="color: #007700">(</span><span style="color: #0000BB">text</span><span style="color: #007700">,&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">id</span><span style="color: #007700">);<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;}&nbsp;
<br /></span><span style="color: #0000BB"></span> </span> </code></code><hr />
 </div></div>
]]>
</content:encoded>
<category domain="http://forum.ragezone.com/f427/">Releases</category>
<dc:creator>Fraysa</dc:creator>
<guid isPermaLink="true">
http://forum.ragezone.com/f427/add-choice-dialog-easy-selections-979948/
</guid>
</item>
```

I want to be able to retrieve each item's title, link, content, and creator.
For example, the item I posted: It's title is "[Release] [Add-on] Choice Dialog Easy Selections", the content is under:

```
<content:encoded>
```

And the creator is:

```
<dc:creator>Fraysa</dc:creator>
```

How can I do that? I'm having real issues on messing with Regex. I tried to split it but messed up. Can anyone help?
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code :

```
String lines="<title><![CDATA[ [Release] [Add-on] Choice Dialog Easy Selections ]]></title>";
String REGEX="(?<=<title><\\!\\[CDATA\\[)(.*)(?=\\]\\]></title>)";
Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile(REGEX);
Matcher matcher =pattern.matcher(lines);
if(matcher.find()){
    System.out.println("Title  : "+matcher.group());
}
```

I used lookbehind `(?<=)` and look ahead `(?=)` expressions .